# Cant find element Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, hyperlink, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to find a solution to this forever. I'm trying to click on a hyperlink.For some reason I just can't find the element, I have tried to also get the value outside the href so I can open a new tab and go to the link, but that didn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the html code and the link I'm trying to click/find.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEhAv.jpg

The code I have tried so far:

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/a').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Verify Email')])[2]").get_attribute('href')
```

There are 2 hrefs, 1 is random and contains the website's url and the second one is the link I'm looking for.

Comment: Please include the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

If the inner text of the link is always going to be the same and there are no other links with the same inner text value, you can use `browser.find_element_by_link_text(' Verify Email ')`. This will return the first anchor tag that the driver finds with the matching text value, or if none are found it will throw a `NoSuchElement` error.

Comment: Nope, It gave me the NoSuchElement error

Comment: Make sure that the text you entered as a argument to the function matches what is in the html exactly, otherwise it won't find it.

Comment: Everything matches and it still doesn't work

Comment: Is this page something you are going to from a `browser.get()` call or a page you are navigating to through the webpage and then trying to find the element?